# IO Error [Errno 5] with long term Serial Connection in Python

Tags: python, ubuntu, arduino, serial-port, ioerror

I am running a fairly simple python code on Ubuntu that is to communicate with an Arduino. The code works as expected for about 15 minutes and then throws an I/O error [Errno 5]. I have searched through many threads about this error message but I can't seem to find a solution that fits my needs.

The python code sends commands to the Arduino through serial port and the arduino does whatever that command is. When this error is thrown, the Arduino is forced off of its original port number. It goes from '/dev/ttyACM1' to '/dev/ttyACM2'

At first I thought it had to do with the Arduino's autoreset function, which I bypassed with a 120 ohm resistor between the Reset and +5V pins. This did not solve the problem.

Next, I thought it was because the Ubuntu machine suspends itself due to inactivity, so I disabled that power saving feature, but no improvement.

Also, I leave the terminal session open where the python code is ran originally.

I'm sure the problem has to do with the serial port number issue since the error is triggered by a failed ser.write command

The subroutine of the python code which generates this error is as follows:

```
def sc_loop(ptime,maxiter, file):

iter = 1              ## Initialize cycle count
totalvol = 0
cyclevol = 0
while iter < maxiter:
    ts = time.time()
    st = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    print >>file, st, " - pump cycle #", iter
    ## Tell the arduino to begin pumping
    ser.write("1".encode())
    pump = ser.readline()
    if pump == 'P':
        ts = time.time()
        st = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        print >>file, st, " - Sample chamber pump turned ON"
    ts = time.time()
    st = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    print >>file, st, " - Sample chamber pump turned ON"
    time.sleep(ptime)
    ser.write("2".encode())
    ts2 = time.time()
    st2 = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts2).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    print >>file, st2, " - Sample Chamber Pump turned OFF"
    print >>file, st2, " - Pump was on for",ts2-ts, "seconds"
    cyclevol = 0.0667*(ts2-ts)
    print >>file, st2, " - ", cyclevol," mL of sample were pumped this cycle"
    totalvol = totalvol+cyclevol
    print >>file, st2, " - ", totalvol, " mL of sample have been pumped so far"
    time.sleep(3)
    runcamera(file) ## Run camera
    ## imaged = raw_input("Sample is ready for imaging [Press any key once imaged] ")
    iter = iter+1
return
```

This code works flawlessly, albeit temporarily. My question is, what causes this error after 10-15 minutes of the python code running?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Let me know if there is any other part of the code, that you might need to see like where the serial connection is established etc. I tried to keep the question as concise as possible but can edit if necessary.

Comment: If the device is being renamed, the system `udev` is likely involved. Run `udevadm monitor` and see what triggers the rename.

Comment: Thanks @tdelaney, I tried this and saw that the port becomes 'removed'. As if it is being physically unplugged from the machine. Once this happens, it gets 'added' to /dev/ttyACM2. I couldn't extract any reason for this from the udevadm monitor but this confirmed that it is being removed and renamed. Is there a special part of the udev monitor I should pay attention to?

Comment: `udev monitor --property --environment` will give you more information. The system logs should have more info.

Comment: The problem may be on the arduino side. It drops its usb connection which is what starts the udev action on the ubuntu box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2057988

The issue is due to udev giving dynamic names to devices. After a while, the arduino is re-registered by the machine and is assigned a new port number. It is assigned a new port number because the driver burps while it 'removes' and 'adds' the arduino almost simultaneously.

Creating a new rule for udev to assign the device a static port will help.

Comment: Great solution. My guess is that OP will get an IOError when the device is removed and will need to reopen (with retries and sleep so that udev has a chance to finish) with the same name.

Comment: Thanks @tdelaney! You've been a huge help! I'll keep this thread updated with any progress/question

Answer (score 1):

Well, I run into the same error. What I did that really works well is to simply close with `connection.close()` the serial connection and re-establish it with `connection = serial.Serial(port,baudrate = baudrate)`. Particularly when **IOError[Errno 5]** occurs. You can use try and catch to handle that.